# How to get zeros for no values in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

My query is

```
SELECT CASE
WHEN clnt_ntnlty =0 THEN 'Aboriginal'
WHEN clnt_ntnlty =1 THEN 'Torres Strait Islander'
WHEN clnt_ntnlty =2 THEN 'Both Aboring & Torres Strait' 
WHEN clnt_ntnlty =3 THEN 'Neither Aboring OR Torres Strait'
ELSE 'Not Provided' END AS Identy,
ISNULL(COUNT(clnt_ntnlty), 0) AS Counts
FROM dbo.clientInfo
group by clnt_ntnlty
```

I am getting result as 
[image]

I want all(five row) records with zero if there is no value . I have tried with group by all, it is not working.

Comment: Do you have a table that there is an FK to for the nationality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT Identy, 
    COUNT(clnt_ntnlty) OVER (PARTITION BY Identy) Counts
FROM (
        SELECT 0 Val, 'Aboriginal' Identy UNION
        SELECT 1 Val, 'Torres Strait Islander' Identy UNION
        SELECT 2 Val, 'Both Aboring & Torres Strait' Identy UNION
        SELECT 3 Val, 'Neither Aboring OR Torres Strait' Identy 
    ) x left join dbo.clientInfo t on t.clnt_ntnlty=x.Val
```

Comment: sorry to say.. Error for ur query Msg 1087, Level 15, State 2, Line 33
Must declare the table variable "@".

Answer (score 0):

You can have a subquery which has four values you want and do a `LEFT JOIN` on it.

```
SELECT  a.Identy,
        COALESCE(b.Counts, 0) Counts
FROM    (
            SELECT 'Aboriginal' Identy
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 'Torres Strait Islander' Identy
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 'Both Aboring & Torres Strait' Identy
            UNION ALL 
            SELECT 'Neither Aboring OR Torres Strait' Identy
        ) a LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  CASE
                        WHEN clnt_ntnlty =0 THEN 'Aboriginal'
                        WHEN clnt_ntnlty =1 THEN 'Torres Strait Islander'
                        WHEN clnt_ntnlty =2 THEN 'Both Aboring & Torres Strait' 
                        WHEN clnt_ntnlty =3 THEN 'Neither Aboring OR Torres Strait'
                        ELSE 'Not Provided' END AS Identy,
                        ISNULL(COUNT(clnt_ntnlty), 0) AS Counts
            FROM dbo.clientInfo
            group by clnt_ntnlty
        ) b ON a.Identy = b.Identy
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE
WHEN clnt_ntnlty =0 THEN 'Aboriginal'
WHEN clnt_ntnlty =1 THEN 'Torres Strait Islander'
WHEN clnt_ntnlty =2 THEN 'Both Aboring & Torres Strait' 
WHEN clnt_ntnlty =3 THEN 'Neither Aboring OR Torres Strait'
ELSE 'Not Provided' END AS Identy,
SUM(CASE WHEN I.clnt_ntnlty IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS c_ntnlty
FROM 
(VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(9)) N (ntnlty) LEFT JOIN
dbo.clientInfo I ON N.ntnlty = ISNULL(I.clnt_ntnlty,9)

GROUP BY N.ntnlty
```

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 21
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'VALUES'.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question correctly where you want to count the "zeros" then this is a simple answer then.

Change - `ISNULL(COUNT(clnt_ntnlty), 0) AS Counts`

To - `COUNT(ISNULL(clnt_ntnlty, 0)) AS Counts`

If this is not what you are looking for then will be a little more desciptive.

Comment: Tried it.. but giving the same result

Answer (score 0):

OK, i am not proud of the following script because it's a dirty solution; Union all the possible values and subtract by one to remove that addition

```
SELECT CASE
WHEN cte.clnt_ntnlty =0 THEN 'Aboriginal'
WHEN cte.clnt_ntnlty =1 THEN 'Torres Strait Islander'
WHEN cte.clnt_ntnlty =2 THEN 'Both Aboring & Torres Strait' 
WHEN cte.clnt_ntnlty =3 THEN 'Neither Aboring OR Torres Strait'
ELSE 'Not Provided' END AS Identy,
ISNULL(COUNT(cte.clnt_ntnlty) - 1, 0) AS Counts
FROM (select ID,clnt_ntnlty from dbo.clientInfo
union select 0,'0' as clnt_ntnlty
union select 1, '1' as clnt_ntnlty
union select 2, '2' as clnt_ntnlty
union select 3, '3' as clnt_ntnlty) as cte
group by clnt_ntnlty
```

change the union select to match your schema

Comment: error:  Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 44
Invalid column name 'ID'.
Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 44
No column was specified for column 1 of 'cte'.